# Creating a value of a type f#

Tags: types, f#

```
  type ExcludeToIncludeCombinationsWhenMergingJson = JsonProvider<"""
  {
    "data": {
      "excludeToIncludeList": [
        {
          "budgetType": "bottomUp",
          "budgetYear": 2019,
          "outletId": 9223372036854775806
        },
        {
          "budgetType": "bottomUp",
          "budgetYear": 2019
        }
      ]
    }
  }
  """,SampleIsList=true>
```

I am new to f#.I have a type like this. How can I create A value of this type?
I am really struggling with this.

I tried this

```
let r = ExcludeToIncludeCombinationsWhenMergingJson.Root(ExcludeToIncludeCombinationsWhenMergingJson.Data(ExcludeToIncludeCombinationsWhenMergingJson.ExcludeToIncludeList([{BudgetType = "bottomup"; BudgetYear = 2019; OutletId = 5;}])))
```

It does not work. Any help will be appreciated. Any kind of document that I can follow

Answer (score 0):

To create a value of the type `ExcludeToIncludeCombinationsWhenMergingJson` you need to call the method `Parse` with input is a real json string you want to parse, like this:

```
let jsonString = ... // read from file or network
let r = ExcludeToIncludeCombinationsWhenMergingJson.Parse jsonString
// now use r
r.Data.ExcludeToIncludeList ...
```

Notice that the `Parse` method will throw an exception when the `jsonString` is invalid (not have correct structure/format as specified in the sample string).

To parse the sample json string itself, you can use the method `GetSample` or `GetSamples` (the later is available only when the sample json string is a list).

Also notice that your posted sample json string is not a list, so please remove the `,SampleIsList=true`

For more details, please refer to the official document of Json Type Provider: http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/JsonProvider.html